# How can I dereference a hashref constant?

Tags: perl

Let's say I have a hashref constant like the following:

```
use constant DOGS => {
    Lassie => 'collie',
    Benji  => 'mutt',
    Scooby => 'great dane',
    Goofy  => '???'
};
```

How can I dereference it properly to get say.. they keys out of it?

```
warn ref DOGS; # HASH at untitled line 12.
warn keys( %{DOGS} ); # Warning: something's wrong (empty list)
warn keys( DOGS ); # Type of arg 1 to keys must be hash (not constant item)
```

The following is the only way I can seem to make it work:

```
my $dogs = DOGS;
warn keys( %$dogs ); # LassieBenjiGoofyScooby at untitled line 15.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are several ways to define constants in Perl, each with different good and bad points.  What problem are you solving with constants in this case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will usually work for you:

```
%{DOG()}
```

Constants are generally just subs. But for *ease* (and looks), you might prefer to use [`Readonly`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Readonly), as suggested in PBP.

```
Readonly::Hash my %DOG => 
    ( Lassie => 'collie'
    , Benji  => 'mutt'
    , Scooby => 'great dane'
    , Goofy  => '???'
    );
```

Answer (score 5):

Perldoc is your friend: `perldoc constants`

> You can get into trouble if you use
>   constants in a context which
>   automatically quotes barewords (as is
>   true for any subroutine call).  For
>   example,
>          you can't say $hash{CONSTANT} because "CONSTANT" will be interpreted
>   as a string.  Use $hash{CONSTANT()} or
>   $hash{+CONSTANT} to prevent the bare-
>          word quoting mechanism from kicking in.  Similarly, since the "=>"
>   operator quotes a bareword immediately
>   to its left, you have to say
>   "CONSTANT()
>          => 'value'" (or simply use a comma in place of the big arrow)
>   instead of "CONSTANT => 'value'".

`warn keys %{DOG()}` should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Force it into list context...

```
warn keys(%{(DOGS)});
```

Comment: -1 for cargo cult. It is not forcing list context but breaks hash key name Perl magic.